# DrmManagerClient works on local files, but not on files in a server

Tags: android, drm, android-drm

I am trying to implement DRM in my application.
But I am facing a problem. `canHandle()` always returns false.
And `DrmManagerClient.getOriginalMimeType(Uri)`; always returns null for http links.
But for files in the storage, everything is working fine.

```
DrmManagerClient mDrmManager;
mDrmManager = new DrmManagerClient(this);
String testUri = myUrl;
String mimeType = getOriginalMimeType( testUri );
```

Below is the method to get mimetype but unfortunately canHandle() always return false.

```
    // get MimeType
public String getOriginalMimeType(String uri){
    String mime = null;

    try {
        if( mDrmManager.canHandle(Uri.parse(uri), null) ){
            mime = mDrmManager.getOriginalMimeType(Uri.parse(uri));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, e.toString());
    }

    return mime;
}
```

Am I missing something?
The obvious would have been that probably the url I am using is not good, but
I have tried different urls which work in another application but the outcome is the same.
I have set INTERNET permission in the manifest file too. I am running out of ideas what is the problem.
After digging into DrmManagerClient source code, I noticed that canHandle() is defined as follows:

```
/**
 * Checks whether the given MIME type or URI can be handled.
 *
 * @param uri URI for the content to be handled.
 * @param mimeType MIME type of the object to be handled
 *
 * @return True if the given MIME type or URI can be handled; false if they cannot be handled.
 */
public boolean canHandle(Uri uri, String mimeType) {
    if ((null == uri || Uri.EMPTY == uri) && (null == mimeType || mimeType.equals(""))) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uri or the mimetype should be non null");
    }
    return canHandle(convertUriToPath(uri), mimeType);
}
```

What `canHandle(Uri uri , String mimeType)` is basically the same as `canHandle( String path, mimeType )` because it is converting Uri to Path.
Does this mean that Http Urls wont work?

Comment: Hello Ninja,I am trying to implement DRM in my application , got struck with lots of issues ,can you provide any sample on that .It would be very help full thanks in advance

Comment: @KomalG The most comprehensible sample I found back then was in Samsung website. Can not find it now.
Have a look at this one. https://github.com/NicePeopleAtWork/NicePlayers/blob/master/android/VideoView_MediaPlayer/NicePluginAndroidTest/src/com/widevine/demo/WidevineDrm.java

Comment: Hi Lazy Ninja , thank you so much for your response, i have see that link i found "NicePluginAndroidTest" project ==> WidevineDrm.java and VideoViewWidevineActivity.java i am playing the video from internal storage(/storage/emulated/0/Android/) using above 2 files and pulling the video out and pushing into another device,That video is playing well without any issues (Video is not being protected) My Aim is to protect the video from another device while playing using "DRM" (DrmManagerClient is not working on media files)please explain 
please explain Ninja Thanks

Comment: Hello Ninja plz provide any sample on that .It would be very help full thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the problem lies in the urls.
I tested with these two links and everything is fine now.

Stream 1: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/wvmedia/sintel_main_720p_4br_tp.wvm

Stream 2: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/wvmedia/starz_main_720p_6br_tp.wvm

Hope it helps someone in the future.